# Hash password before mongodb update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So i've spent a while trying to solve this. Basically I have a user profile update page, when the user inputs the new credentials I want to update my mongo db. When I update it everything does through normally and my mongo server gets updated but when I log in, I use bcrypt to match the hashed password and unhashed password and this is what is giving me my error because the updated password isn't hashed.

Update mongo:

```
 const { email, password, password2 } = req.body;
 const _id = ObjectID(req.user);

  User.updateOne(
      { _id },
      { $set: { email: email, password: password } },
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          req.flash('success_msg', 'profile updated');
          res.redirect('profile');
        }
      }
    );
```

This is my try at hashing the password. It gives an error in the console(Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters). I tried to solve this by making the object id .toString but it still gave an error:

```
  const { email, password, password2 } = req.body;
  const _id = ObjectID(req.user);

    User.updateOne(
      { _id },
      { $set: { email: email, password: password } },
      (err, user) => {
        const updatedPassword = password;
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(updatedPassword.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
              if (err) {
                throw err;
              }
              updatedPassword.password = hash;
              updatedPassword.save();
            });
          });
        }
        req.flash('success_msg', 'profile updated');
        res.redirect('profile');
      }
    );
```

I'm a kinda new to express so sorry if this is messy. Also if you find a solution please explain it and if you need more code I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

You likely deserialize the user in a middleware not shown and so the following line should change from:

```
const _id = ObjectID(req.user);
```

to

```
const _id = new ObjectID(req.user._id);
```

Comment: It submits the new user but it doesn't hash the password so I get a password error on my form.